# VBScript issue with values in a table

Tags: vbscript, kofax

I have this code to build a table and send it via e-mail to business.
 They want to know, on a daily basis, how many files were transferred from a Source to a Destination, and if there's a difference in the number of files (possible failed/corrupted transfers). All this by folder. 
The problem is that this code somehow misses the row of the Number of Missing Files in the Destination folder. It seems like if it were attributing the row in a random manner. The image below shows that even though the folder 3 is complete, it does say there is 1 missing file, and the folder 5 has 1 missing file (59 in the Source and only 58 in the Destination folder) and it states 0 missing items. 
 What am I missing here?

[image: Error]

The code is:

```
' >>> init a Windows Shell object to run system commands
SET WshShell = WScript.CREATEOBJECT("WScript.Shell")
' >>> load email Class code
WDIR = "D:\Kofax_Scripts"
SET objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
SET mailObjectFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile( WDIR & "\email.vbs", 1)
Execute mailObjectFile.ReadAll()

' >>> TEST passed arguments
If WScript.Arguments.Count = 0 Then
  Wscript.echo vbCr & vbLf & "Usage is: cscript.exe //nologo Kofax_SAP_crosscheck.vbs DEV|PRD [date]" & vbCrLf
  Wscript.echo               "If date is not given, script uses system current date. To run this script for other dates, you must pass it in format YYYY-MM-DD"
  wscript.quit
End If 
If WScript.Arguments.Item(0) = "DEV" Then
    Wscript.echo "Running in DEV..."
ElseIf WScript.Arguments.Item(0) = "PRD" Then
    Wscript.echo "Running in PRD..."
Else    
  Wscript.echo vbCr & vbLf & "Environment parameter is wrong! Possible choices:  DEV|PRD"
  wscript.quit
End If
' >>> Get today's date
t1=Now()
Wscript.echo "starting at: " & t1
' >>> Set date to use for the files' date crosscheck 
Dim date_cross_check
If WScript.Arguments.Count = 2 Then
    date_cross_check =  CDate(WScript.Arguments.Item(1))
Else
    date_cross_check = t1
End If
' >>> compose date string from the files pathname to be checked
ano = Year(date_cross_check)
mes = Month(date_cross_check)
dia = Day(date_cross_check)
date_cross_check_str = ano & "/" & mes & "/" & dia

' Set lists of Folders to cross-check
Set KofaxFolders = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set SapFolders = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

KofaxFolders.Add "AMOS", CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
KofaxFolders.Add "bomdia", CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
KofaxFolders.Add "cockpit", CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
KofaxFolders.Add "irreg", CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
KofaxFolders.Add "miro", CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
KofaxFolders.Add "BSP", CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

SapFolders.Add "AMOS", CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
SapFolders.Add "bomdia", CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
SapFolders.Add "cockpit", CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
SapFolders.Add "irreg", CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
SapFolders.Add "miro", CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
SapFolders.Add "BSP", CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

' init dictionaries
For each key in KofaxFolders
    KofaxFolders(key).Add "files", CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    KofaxFolders(key).Add "count", 0
Next
     For each key in SapFolders
            SapFolders(key).Add "files", CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            SapFolders(key).Add "missing", 0
            SapFolders(key).Add "count", 0  
        Next

      ' init File System Object
    Dim objFSO
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    ' Loop on KofaxFolders to fill contents folders
    for each key in KofaxFolders
        fldr = "D:\Projetos\EXPORT\" & key &"\Save\"& ano &"\"& mes &"\"& dia
        If (objFSO.FolderExists(fldr)) Then
            Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(fldr)
            For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
                ' Don't consider garbage files like Thumbs.db       
                If ( objFile.name <> "Thumbs.db" ) Then 
                    ' Wscript.echo "Folder : " & key  & "Filename: " & objFile.name & ", size (bytes): " & objFile.size
                    KofaxFolders(key)("files").Add objFile.name, objFile.size
                    KofaxFolders(key)("count") = KofaxFolders(key)("count") + 1
                End If
            Next    
        End If
    next

    ' Loop on SapFolders to fill contents folders
    for each key in SapFolders
        Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("\\iftpv01\TPP\transdata\InB\OCRSave\Save"&key)
        'WScript.Echo "Folder : " & key
        For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
            'Wscript.echo "Folder : " & key  & "Filename: " & objFile.name & ", size (bytes): " & objFile.size      
            ' Check only SAP files with last Modified Date equal to specified date
            ' --------------------------------------------------------------------
            If ( DateDiff("d",objFile.DateLastModified, CDate(date_cross_check)) = 0 )Then
                ' Don't consider garbage files like Thumbs.db
                If ( objFile.name <> "Thumbs.db" ) Then 
                    SapFolders(key)("files").Add objFile.name, objFile.size
                    SapFolders(key)("count") = SapFolders(key)("count") + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next
    next

        ' ------------------------'
        ' Start new empty log file'
        ' ------------------------'
        Dim log_file
        log_file = WDIR & "\tmp\kofax_sap_crosscheck.log"
        Set objLogFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(log_file,True)   
        objLogFile.Close
        ' open file in write mode
        Set objLogFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(log_file, 2)

        ' Loop on KofaxFolders Contents and check if file exists in SAP structure
        For each key in KofaxFolders
            For each file in KofaxFolders(key)("files")
                If ( NOT SapFolders(key)("files").Exists(file) ) Then  
                    objLogFile.WriteLine("file " & file & " is missing from InB SAP folder "&key)
                    SapFolders(key)("missing") = SapFolders(key)("missing") + 1
                Else 
                    ' If file size is different between Kofax and SAP, this may be due to corrupt transfer
                    If SapFolders(key)("files")(file) <> KofaxFolders(key)("files")(file) Then
                        objLogFile.WriteLine("file " & file & " has not same size in SAP and Kofax " & key &" Folders!!!  Kofax size:  " _
                            & KofaxFolders(key)("files")(file) & "| SAP size: " _
                            & SapFolders(key)("files")(file) _
                        )
                        SapFolders(key)("missing") = SapFolders(key)("missing") + 1
                    End If 
                End If 
            Next
        Next
        ' close log file
        objLogFile.Close
        ' compute execution time
        exec_time = datediff("s",t1,Now)

        ' Global missing count
        Dim missing_files : missing_files = 0
        For each key in SapFolders
            missing_files = missing_files + SapFolders(key)("missing")
        Next

        ' Build summary HTML table according to "missing_files" count
        Dim rep_table : rep_table  = ""
        if ( missing_files > 0 )Then
            rep_table = "<table border=""1""><tr><th>Folder</th><th>Nr of files Source</th><th>Nr of files Dest</th><th>Nr of Files missing Dest</th></tr>"
            For each key in SapFolders
                rep_table = rep_table & "<tr><td>" & key & "</td><td align=""right"">" &  KofaxFolders(key)("count") &"</td><td align=""right"">" & SapFolders(key)("count") & "</td>"
                if ( SapFolders(key)("missing") > 0 ) Then
                    rep_table = rep_table & "<td align=""right"" bgcolor=""#FF0000"">" 
                Else
                    rep_table = rep_table & "<td align=""right"">" 
                End If 
                rep_table = rep_table & SapFolders(key)("missing") &"</td></tr>"
            Next
        Else
            rep_table = "<table border=""1""><tr><th>Pasta</th><th>Nº ficheiros no Kofax</th><th>Nº ficheiros no SAP</th></tr>"
            For each key in SapFolders
                rep_table = rep_table & "<tr><td>" & key & "</td><td align=""right"">" &  KofaxFolders(key)("count") &"</td><td align=""right"">" & SapFolders(key)("count") & "</td></tr>"
            Next
        End If
        rep_table = rep_table & "</table>"
```

Comment: Is that the whole code or do you have `On Error Resume Next` anywhere?

Comment: This is the whole code.

Comment: If it's the whole code what does `[...]` refer to?

Comment: Correction: there is no On Error Resume Next, but yes here are more code

Comment: Sorry, updated the code above!

Comment: What are `Sapfolders` and `KofaxFolders` and what is `key`? It seems that there is something buggy about how you are using those data structures but you haven't shown how they are created or initialized. My guess is that the keys are not properly coordinated between those two data structures, but this is only a guess since you haven't given enough details.

Comment: @JohnColeman I updated the code, now it contains all the code. Sorry, I didn't want it to be huge and cut some info that would be needed. Now it's complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not 100% sure about what is happening here, but I think that the issue is that `SapFolders` is a dictionary and you are using the line

```
For each key in SapFolders
```

to iterate over it when creating the table. The order of keys in such an iteration is (essentially) random. In your case, it *isn't* true that the loop iterate over the keys `"AMOS", "bomdia", "cockpit", "irreg", "miro", "BSP"` in that order.

What you could do is to create an array:

```
keys = Array("AMOS", "bomdia", "cockpit", "irreg", "miro", "BSP")
```

and replace every loop which begins

```
For each key in SapFolders
```

by

```
For i = 0 to UBound(keys)
   key = keys(i)
```

(and maybe do a similar move for iterations involving `KofaxFolders`).

This will guarantee that you know the order with which you are populating the report table.